# what does mean "By this point"

Tags: meaning

**By this point** in their careers, most students have already seen a ...

here, what does mean "By this point"? does it mean "so far"?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite.

- **By this point** would be used to mark a point in time in a sentence or story about the past.
- **So far** would be to mark the present.

.

> By this point yesterday, I already had twice as much work done.

versus

> So far today, I have twice as much work done compared to yesterday.